# How to use the default color picker in NSToolbar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm learning Cocoa. And this is my simple OS X app:

[image]

It contains a custom view, where the white rect is drown, a toolbar, and a slider. I want to change the rect's fill color by clicking on the 'Colors' item in the toolbar and choosing new color in the color palette.

How can I get the new color from the palette? I know it has the "NSToolbarShowColorsItem" identifier, but don't know how to use it.

Can you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider walking through a couple of basic Cocoa tutorials to learn about fundamental Cocoa concepts.

A number of resources to check out:

- [CocoaDevCentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Tutorials on CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/CocoaTutorials)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, I know these sites. But are there any action methods for that color picker, something like - (IBAction)sliderMoved:(id)sender;